# how can i dismiss a particular toast from within the toast itself in react-toastify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toast, react-toastify

I want to create a toast with two buttons "accept" and "reject".
when I click **reject** I want to dismiss the only toast which contains these two buttons.

i simply want the toast to disappear when i click the reject button inside the toast.

Here is my custom toat with `callingToast` component-

```
const toastId = toast(CallingToast, {
      ...toastOptions,
      autoClose: 60000,
      closeButton: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      closeOnClick: false,
    });
```

Below is my calling toast component-

```
import React from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

export default function CallingToast() {
  return (
    <>
      <button>accept</button>
      <button
        onClick={}
      >
        reject
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried calling `toast.dismiss()` on the reject butto, but it dismisses all of the toast which I don't want.

I also tried passing `toastId` to the component somehow but it obviously didn't work. I couldn't find any related questions as well that's why posting my own.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `toast.dismiss` without argument, all the displayed toasts will be removed. An id is always returned each time you display a toast so use that to remove a toast programmatically by calling `toast.dismiss(id)`.

Here is the example taken from the [documentation](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/remove-toast)-

```
import React from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

function Example(){
  const toastId = React.useRef(null);

  const notify = () => toastId.current = toast("Lorem ipsum dolor");

  const dismiss = () =>  toast.dismiss(toastId.current);

  const dismissAll = () =>  toast.dismiss();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Notify</button>
      <button onClick={dismiss}>Dismiss</button>
      <button onClick={dismissAll}>Dismiss All</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i know this but i want to do this from inside of the toast itself, that is what i am asking is there a way to get this toastId inside the toast itself or any other way to close it from the inside without using closeButton.

Comment: Can't you pass the saved id of toast when clicking on the close button?

Comment: toastId is returned when toast is created so i cannot pass it to the callingToast component before it is even returned or saved.

Answer (score 1):

So, I am answering my own question because after some digging and lots of trial and error. I finally found the solution to my problem.

I found out during my research that if you render a component inside toast then that component automatically receives `closeToast` and `toastProps` as props.

So in CallingToast component, When the reject button is clicked i called `closeToast()` function and it did the work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

export default function CallingToast({closeToast}) {
  return (
    <>
      <button>accept</button>
      <button
        onClick={closeToast()}
      >
        reject
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Only if documentation was a little better it would have saved me a lot of time.